# Blender renders the input video instead of Composite node

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I stabilized a video in the Movie Clip Editor and used the result as a Stabilize 2D block in the Node Editor. But, when I animate it, it is reproducing the original video, instead of the Composite block.

I followed a Blender 2.72 tutorial by the letter, so it could have something to do with the version, but why would Blender get the input instead of the output? What am I doing wrong?[image: Screen capture]

Comment: You probably still have the video strip in Video Sequence Editor, then Blender ignores the scene and renders the strip from VSE.

Comment: Hi, @Mzidare. I erased the strips from the Video Sequence Editor, but Blender is still rendering only the input video and ignoring everything else. I can even disconnect the Composite block altogether.

Comment: Solved it by trial and error. The Video Sequence Editor didn't have the scene strip. I thought the Composite block alone would override it if it were empty.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by trial and error. The Video Sequence Editor didn't have the scene strip. I thought the Composite block alone would override it if it were empty.